# Send download link to Amazon Bucket folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to send someone a link to download a folder stored in an amazon S3 bucket. Is this possible?

Comment: No it's not possible. The best option would be to zip up the folder, store the zip file in S3, and give someone a link to that.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for the answer man

Comment: @MarkB By any chance do you know how to download many files at once? when I select multiple files in the bucket, the "download" option is disabled from the "actions" menu

Comment: I don't think you can't do that via the web UI. You would need to use something like the AWS CLI tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the AWS CLI

```
aws s3 sync s3://<bucket>/path/to/folder/ .
```

There are many options if you need to filter specific files etc ... check the [doc  page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Minio Client aka mc for this. It is open source and S3 compatible. [mc policy command](https://minio.io) should do this for you.

Set bucket to "download" on Amazon S3 cloud storage.

$ mc policy download s3/your_bucket

This will add downloadable policy on all the objects inside bucket name `your_bucket` and an object with name `yourobject`
can be accessed with URL below.

https://your_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/yourobject

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://minio.io)